# unable to setup master in replication(my.cnf) in a ec2 linux instance

Tags: mysql, database-replication

> [mysqld] datadir = /mnt/mysql/lib/data socket  =
> /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock user = mysql character-set-server = utf8
> max_connections = 750 max_allowed_packet = 1G symbolic-links = 0
> performance_schema server-id = 03082022 expire_log_days = 3
> skip-name-resolve key_buffer_size = 12G innodb_buffer_pool_size = 5G
> innodb_file_per_table = 1 innodb_data_file_path =
> ibdata1:4G:autoextend innodb_log_file_size = 512M
> innodb_thread_concurrency = 10 innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 1024M
> innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2 sort_buffer_size = 8M wait_timeout
> = 60 sync_binlog = 0 innodb_io_capacity = 600 innodb_doublewrite = 0 event_scheduler = ON bingo-format = MIXED transaction-isolation =
> READ_COMMITTED thread_cache_size = 750

when i set these and when i restart my server its failing

Comment: What does the error log imply ? Besides, what is a `bingo-format = MIXED` ? Did you mean to use `binlog-format` ?

Comment: ya that was a typo and we need not setup all these parameters to establish a replication few and depending on the need world work perfectly

Answer (score 0):

refer the website the issue will be solved no need of all these parameters

https://devopscube.com/setup-mysql-master-slave-replication/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).